# Call ASP.NET page method from class file method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project(ASP.NET website) where i need to call method in webpage from a class.

///Default Page Method is

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       BLMethods objBLMethods = new BLMethods();
       objBLMethods.BindingDataToControls();
    }

    public void BindGridView(List<clsPerson> objPersonList)
    {                      
      GridView1.DataSource = objPersonList.ToList();
      GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

`

class file structure is

```
    public class BLMethods 
    {
        public BLMethods()
        {
          List<clsPerson> objPersonList = new List<clsPerson>();
          clsPerson objPerson = new clsPerson();
          objPerson.personID = i;
          objPerson.personName = "Person" + i;
          objPersonList.Add(objPerson);
          BindGridView(objPersonList);
        }
    }
```

clsPerson Class:

```
public class clsPerson 
{ 
    public int personID; 
    public string personName; 
}
```

As shown in the above program, I need to call BindGridView method of page from constructor of BLMethods class

Comment: Hi. Wouldn't the last line in the BLMethods ctor throw a compilation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it the other way around. Add the method to the class (with a GridView as an argument):

```
public class BLMethods 
{
    public BLMethods(GridView gv)
    {
      List<clsPerson> objPersonList = new List<clsPerson>();
      clsPerson objPerson = new clsPerson();
      objPerson.personID = i;
      objPerson.personName = "Person" + i;
      objPersonList.Add(objPerson);
      BindGridView(gv,objPersonList);
    }
    private void BindGridView(GridView gv, List<clsPerson> objPersonList)
    {                      
      gv.DataSource = objPersonList.ToList();
      gv.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Default Page Method is

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       BLMethods objBLMethods = new BLMethods(GridView1);
       objBLMethods.BindingDataToControls();
    }

}
```

Try giving getters and setters to your clsPerson class properties:

```
public class clsPerson 
{ 
    public int personID {get;set;} 
    public string personName {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: When i followed your approach, i'm getting error as, [The data source for GridView with id 'GridView1' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content.]

Comment: @PavanKumar Can we see the clsPerson class?

Comment: public class clsPerson
        {
           public int personID;
           public string personName;
        }

Answer (score 1):

You should be returning only data from business rule class and bind  grid view in the code behind class.

you can make method in the class which will return the `List<clsPerson>` and on page load bind it with your girdview:

```
public class BLMethods 
    {
        public BLMethods()
        {

        }

        public List<clsPerson> GetPersons()
        {
          List<clsPerson> objPersonList = new List<clsPerson>();
          clsPerson objPerson = new clsPerson();
          objPerson.personID = i;
          objPerson.personName = "Person" + i;
          objPersonList.Add(objPerson);

          return objPersonList ;
        }
    }
```

and in code behind of page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       BindGridView();
    }

    public void BindGridView()
    {             
      BLMethods objBLMethods = new BLMethods();
      GridView1.DataSource = objBLMethods.GetPersons();
      GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Here in BLMethods i need to check for authorization of user and if he is valid, I need to call BindGridView or navigate to Error page

Comment: for checking autorization why not use forms authentication

Comment: We are using DataBase for authorization, by sending username, password, pagename to the procedure, we get a response object

Comment: @PavanKumar - Your class is doing too many things.  Have a separate class that deals with authentication and perform that check and redirect based on the result from there.  Then have your person class just return the data based on the user.  Don't try to pull your front end code into your back end.

Comment: @Paddy. The concept you explained is unclear to me. Can you explain me with the above code that i mentioned.

Comment: you can call that on page load to check if user is authorized then continue else redirect

Answer (score 1):

You should look to separate your concerns correctly.  Based on comments and queries from Ehsan Sajjad's answer:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!new AuthenticationHelper().IsUserAuthorisedForPeople(Request.User.Identity))
       {
           Response.Redirect("NaughtyNaughty.aspx");
       }

       BindGridView();
    }

    public void BindGridView()
    {                      
      PersonHelper helper = new PersonHelper();
      GridView1.DataSource = helper.GetPeople();
      GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

public class AuthenticationHelper()
{
     public bool IsUserAuthorisedForPeople(string userName) {
        return true; //Do your auth here.
     }
}

public class PersonHelper
{

    private void GetPeople()
    {                      
      List<clsPerson> objPersonList = new List<clsPerson>();

      //Populate your list of people.

      return objPersonList; 
      //BTW - hungarian notation for your naming is just going to make your 
      //code look cluttered...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to work other way around. You write the method in BL that returns the objPersonList call it from your page to bind.

Comment: When i followed your approach, i'm getting error as, [The data source for GridView with id 'GridView1' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns. Ensure that your data source has content.]