# Call page method from class file

Tags: c#, asp.net

My page codebehind is

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    BLMethods objBLMethods = new BLMethods();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        objBLMethods.DisplayValue();
    }


    public void BindTextbox(string s)
    {  
       TextBox1.Text=s;
    }
}
```

and i have a class BlMethods

```
public class BLMethods
{
    public void DisplayValue()
    {
       BindTextbox("This is from Bl Class");
    }
}
```

This is generating error, BindTextBox method is in page which cannot be accessible from another class unless an object is created.

Is there any chance to call page method without (creating object to page or making methods static)

Comment: You asked this yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602432/call-asp-net-page-method-from-class-file-method Why are you repeating the question when you have perfectly fitting answers in the previous thread?

Comment: i was asked in my company to do this in different way. The answers of yesterday didn't satisfy my team leader

Comment: The reason you are finding this difficult is that this is not really the way you should be doing this.  Leave your front end code to handle the front end and only have your logic on the back end.  Closing as dupe of yesterday.

Comment: @PavanKumar - SO isn't here to satisfy the requirements of your boss. You've have had your technical question answered, don't repeat yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a constructor to `BLMethods` which takes `_Default` and assigns it to a field in `BLMethods`:

```
private _Default def;
public BLMethods(_Default def)
{
    this.def = def;
}
```

and in your `_Default` add a constructor to instantiate it:

```
public _Default()
{
    this.objBLMethods = new BLMethods(this);
}
```

But to be honest I think you need to seriously think about your separation of concerns. Try separating your application into distinct layers.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "No".  But you can achieve the same effect some other ways.

One would be to make your page implement an interface that includes the method `BindTextBox`, and pass a parameter of that interface type to your class, either as a constructor parameter or a method parameter.

Another would be to have your object raise an event, which your page could handle.

Finally, you could make your class method accept a delegate parameter that had the signature of `BindTextBox` (such as `Action<string>`) and invoke the delegate within your class.

I'm sure there are other ways as well.

Answer (score 2):

Pass a delegate to the instance.

```
public class BLMethods
{
    readonly Action<string> _displayValue;

    public BLMethods(Action<string> displayValue)
    {
        _displayValue = displayValue;
    }

    public void DisplayValue()
    {
       _displayValue("This is from Bl Class");
    }
}
```

Then new up the instance like this.

```
objBLMethods = new BLMethods(s => BindTextbox(s));
```